# Cross platform diagramming tool

Tags: software-rec, cross-platform, diagrams

I am looking for a cross platform diagramming tool like Viso I can use on Windows, Linux, and OS-X for diagramming. Are there any decent ones available?

Comment: Diagramming what exactly, that would probably help with getting a clear answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...as general as the question is: http://live.gnome.org/Dia a GTK+ based diagram creation program for GNU/Linux, Unix and Windows released under the GPL license.

Comment: I think Dia is the worst application ever made, but there are such few alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

You could use Creately ( https://creately.com )

It's a web based diagramming tool. You don't have to install anything. You can register for an account and start creating diagrams. Since you only need a browser the cross platform issue is solved.

The tool is very similar to Visio. You can use it to draw flowcharts, org charts, UML diagrams, mind maps, network diagrams and many other diagram types. However, Creately is a general diagramming tool so if you want some Visio specific feature then you need to check if the tool supports it. The common features can be found by visiting the [features page](https://creately.com/tour).

I work for Cinergix, makers of the Creately tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) now includes [a flowchart and diagram creation tool](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2009/03/drawing-on-your-creativity-in-docs.html). It's a cross-platform, web-based app. It's not what I'd call full-featured, but it can get the job done in a pinch. It's free and also allows for some team collaboration, with everyone drawing and viewing the same diagram simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The old warhorse of [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/) has a Visio equivalent