# Network modeling software

Tags: networking, modeling

What software is good for modeling network architecture?

Essentially, I want to do this:

[image]

With what software could this be achieved? I need a free or open source solution. I don't need to do a network simulation, just a simple representations tool with nice graphical representation would do the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application to help build diagrams](http://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams)

Comment: [Tool to create architectural overview diagrams](http://superuser.com/questions/18020/tool-to-create-architectural-overview-diagrams/18029#18029), [Cross platform diagramming tool](http://superuser.com/questions/216191/cross-platform-diagramming-tool/216246#216246)

Comment: I think that those do not refer exclusively to free or open source.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for putting the image in, since I couldn't.

Comment: No, but I'm sure you easily pick a few. See also: [Comparison of vector graphics editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_editors#General_information), sort by license.

Comment: @slhck Yes, I already checked out yEd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want an open-source diagramming tool, there are many. The ones that immediately come to my mind are

- inkscape
- dia

Comment: Thanks! I already knew, but forgot, about dia. Does inkscape come with network diagram images?